# Consulta de asignaturas aprobadas no devuelve resultado esperado

Tags: mongodb

Tengo un problema con esta consulta:

```
db.estudiantes.find({materias:{$gt:"3.0"}})
```

La intención de ésta es encontrar los estudiantes que han reprobado por lo menos una materia (la nota minima para pasar es 3.0)

Los datos tienen esta estructura:

```
db.estudiantes.insert({
  id:"1000",
  nombre:"Diego Agreda",
  edad:"15",
  programa:"informatica",
  materias:[{programacion:"5.0",leyes:"2.1",ingles:"4.1"}]
})
```

Al lanzar la consulta

```
 db.estudiantes.find({materias:{$gt:"3.0"}})
```

no me arroja ningún resultado. ¿Por qué sucede eso? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Es posible cambiar tu schema?

Comment: si Angel, es posible modificar el schema, segun lo visto el mas adecuado seria db.estudiantes.insert({_id:1000,nombre:"Diego Agreda",
    edad:15,programa:"informatica",materias:[{programacion:5.0,leyes:2.1,ingles:4.1}]})
pero aun tengo problemas con la consulta en donde debo encontrar los estudiantes que han reprobado por lo menos una materia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparto contigo los operadores de mongo, para que analices cuál es la opción que buscas con tu consulta.

```
$lt     menor que           <

$lte    menor igual que     <=

$gt     mayor que           >

$gte    mayor igual que     >=

$ne     no igual            ¡=
```

Otros puntos que debes considerar son:

- Primero el campo es _id para guardarlo.
- Tus campos deben ser numéricos, para poder hacer la comparación con los operadores gte,lte,gt,lt, etc.
- Debes acceder al campo, ya que es campo embebido deberás realizarlo de la manera siguiente 'como se muestra en la consulta'
- El operador es $gte ya que le indicas que sea mayor o igual que, sino simplemente sera mayor que.
- El {nombre:1}, se refiere que es el campo que quiero visualizar

Replicando tu insert, con modificaciones que considero debes realizar.

```
db.estudiantes.insert({_id:1000,nombre:"Diego Agreda",
    edad:15,programa:"informatica",materias:[{programacion:5.0,leyes:2.1,ingles:4.1}]})
```

Ahora la consulta:

```
    db.estudiantes.find({'materias.programacion':{$gte:3}}, {nombre:1})
```

De lo que me comentas, del {nombre:1}, es la visibilidad de los campos que quiero mostrar, es el equivalente en mysql de:

```
select nombre from estudiantes;
```

No en todas las ocasiones queremos mostrar todos los campos de nuestra tablas, en este caso colección.

Ejemplo:

```
db.e5.find({vistas:{$gte:400}},{github:1,titulo:1,tiempoblog:1})
```

Entonces:

- Colocamos entre {}, el nombre del campo seguido ':' y con el 1 le indicamos true, es decir que queremos que sea visible el resultado es el siguiente.
- Tome un ejemplo que ya tenia, datos ficticios.

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias annelyzzye por responder, tengo dos inquietudes disculpa si es algo obvio pero apenas estoy comenzando con mongo
veo que al lanzar la consulta tan solo me busca por la materia de programacion, como podria realizar la consulta no solo para esa materia, si no para cualquiera, segundo : a que hace referencia {nombre:1}, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Cierto, en un primero momento, no analice bien que solicitabas, sin embargo, tampoco llevo tanto tiempo utilizando mongo, y han sido observaciones que note desde el insert que no eran adecuadas, de tu segunda duda he editado mi respuesta para que se más entendible.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354812/consulta-de-mejor-nota-no-devuelve-resultado-esperado

Answer (score 4):

Gracias al aporte de annelyzzye y angel solucione el esquema y la consulta los cuales quedaron asi

```
db.estudiantes.insert({id:1,nombre:"Esteban Baez",edad:20,programa:"informatica",materias:[{nombre:"programacion",calificacion:5.0},{nombre:"leyes",calificacion:5.0},{nombre:"ingles",calificacion:5.0}]})
```

y la consulta

```
db.estudiantes.find({'materias.calificacion':{$lt:3.0}})
```

Answer (score 3):

Si modificas tu schema, en la propiedad materia de esta manera:

```
materias:[{ nombre: 'Programacion', calificacion: '3.0'}]
```

Puedes filtrar de manera mas sencilla de la siguiente manera:

```
 db.estudiantes.find({'materias.calificacion':{$lt:3}}, {nombre:1})
```

De esta manera obtienes todos los estudiantes que tienen materias con calificaciones menores que `3.0`, ya que según lo que mencionas`3.0` es aprobatoria.

---

## Explicacion

Esta forma de trabajar consiste en que un usuario puede tener infinidad de materias. Un arreglo nos permitirá tener estas materias de manera dinámica y filtrar los resultados más fácilmente (en futuras consultas).

> El codigo esta sobre la marcha. Puede tener errores.